# Cannot install dual boot ubuntu onto windows 10 machine, get grub menu instead of installer

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I have a windows 10 pro machine. I want to dual boot ubuntu 18.04. I have create a bootable USB key. I have in my bios:

"compatibility support module" set to enabled

"secure boot" set to "other os"

When I run this from powershell

```
Confirm-SecureBootUEFI
```

I Get

> false

Yet when I load into the bios and select the USB key as the boot device, I briefly see a message saying

> unknown filesystem (and some other text that disappears too fast to read)

but its gone very fast and then I end up at the GRUB terminal. How can I get to the ubuntu installer?

Comment: You do not normally want this enabled: CSM - UEFI Compatibility Support Module (CSM), which emulates a BIOS mode as you want UEFI boot of live installer. What brand/model system? What video card/chip? Some find they need to redo ISO, use different installer, different USB port, or even different flash drive and then it works. Not one consistent solution.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who finds this.

So, as I had managed to get to the GRUB loader, this implies that the BIOS was indeed trying to boot from the USB key. So if you see this message then at least you know that.

It turns out that I had formatted the USB key as NTFS, and ubuntu didn't like that, when it was trying to boot from the USB key itself. I recreated the USB key and chose FAT32 as the filesystem on the USB key.